# 一般的な画像データをサーバーで５０％程度も圧縮することはできるんですか？

Tags: ios, android

スマートフォンの通信量の消費を減らすためにサーバーとの通信をグーグルなどが提供するデータ圧縮用のサーバーを経由させて圧縮するという以下のようなテクノロジーがあります

- **Google**

> [Chrome のデータセーバーを使ってデータ使用量を減らす](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284?hl=ja)
> データセーバーの仕組み
> データセーバーを使用している状態でウェブページにアクセスすると、Google のサーバーにより、ダウンロードされるデータの量が抑えられます。

- **Opera Max**

> [サーバーを経由する独自技術でデータ通信を圧縮](http://k-tai.impress.co.jp/docs/column/teppan/20150925_721819.html)
> 「Opera Max」は、端末上のあらゆるデータ通信を節約できる常駐型アプリ。セキュアな通信が可能な独自のサーバーを経由し、ユーザーがアクセスしているWebサイトのテキストデータ、画像データ、その他アプリの通信データなどを可能な限り圧縮することで、データ通信量を削減する仕組みになっている。

- **Onavo Extend**

> [スマホのデータ通信量を圧縮してくれる『Onavo Extend』【今日のライフハックツール】](http://www.lifehacker.jp/2015/09/150908onavo_extend.html)
> 現在では、基本的にスマートフォンの月当たりのデータ通信量には上限があり、上限を超えると通信速度が大幅に落とされてしまいます。そんな中、『Onavo Extend』はデータ通信量を圧縮し、転ばぬ先の杖となってくれるアプリです。iPhone、Androidそれぞれに対応しています。
> 大まかな仕組みが分かるように、以下に図解を載せておきます。
>
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここで質問なんですが

> [Chromeは通信量を50%も節約できるなんて知りませんでした。格安SIM運用に最適なブラウザかも。](http://www.mayoinu.com/entry/2015/02/07/192141)
>
> 言わずと知れたブラウザであり、僕も利用している Google Chrome ですが、通信量を50%節約できる設定があります。

にあるようにテキストやHTMLやjavascriptを圧縮して通信量を50%程度削減するなどなら `gzip` などを利用すれば可能だと思ったのですが
この圧縮用サーバーでは画像の圧縮も行ってくれるとのことで `jpg` や `png` などの圧縮画像もさらに圧縮して通信料を削減してくれるとのことです。

`jpg`や`png`は圧縮済みの画像なのでサーバーでもさらに圧縮することはできないと思うのですが
この圧縮とはもしかしてスマホサイズへのサイズの縮小のことを指しているのでしょうか？

Comment: 一番目のリンク先が間違っていませんか？

Comment: 直しました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 8):

> [Some images might look a little fuzzy.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284?p=data_saver_off&rd=1)

らしいので、品質は多少下げていることと思います。
小さい画面で見れば気づかない程度を目標としているでしょうから、ある意味「スマホサイズへのサイズの縮小」と言えるかと思います。

Android向けと同一機能かは分かりませんが、デスクトップのChromeにも[data-saver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-saver/pfmgfdlgomnbgkofeojodiodmgpgmkac)というアドオンが提供されています。
これで、この質問ページを閲覧したところ、質問者さんが添付している79.6kBのJPG画像`D2FZ9.jpg` (ちなみにこの画像は著作権的に大丈夫なのでしょうか)が22.0kBになっていました。

面白いのは、WebP形式に変換されていた事です。
少し色の深みが無くなり、粗さもほんの僅かに見られましたが「劣化」という程の物でもなく、Googleはこの画像フォーマットを広めたいのだろうなと思います。
皆が使ってくれないので、こういったサービスを作って無理くり使わせているのかも知れませんね。

Comment: いやこれは良い回答だと思いました(WebP形式というのは知らなかった)。著作権的には「引用元が【主】、引用先が【従】」という条件を引用元として示していると思われるため問題ないかと思います。リンクを貼ることがウェブの醍醐味ですから何か問題があった場合は第三者が編集・削除することも可能ですので画像は引用元を示し、記載しておこうかと思います

Comment: 余談ですが、この回答( http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/23037/5505 )にあるように静止画フォーマットではなく動画フォーマットにはwebmというグーグルが策定した形式があり、H.264コーデック の置き換えが狙われているようです。

Comment: wikipedia( https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP ) によると「非可逆のWebPは1フレームのWebMである」とのことです

Answer (score 6):

JPEGは非可逆圧縮なので画質を落とせば圧縮率は上げられます。

PNGは可逆圧縮ですので「可逆」の範囲で圧縮率を上げるのは難しいですが、元データを復元できなくても良いのならデコード→圧縮しやすいよう加工→エンコードで同様に圧縮率は上げられます。

他にもメタデータを削除する、大きなサイズの画像(どうせ縮小して表示される)は縮小→拡大で解像度を下げる、など方法はいろいろあります。

---

WebPの話が出ていますが、このように高い圧縮率を実現できるフォーマットに変換するのも一つの方法です。ただし、あまりメジャーでないフォーマットへの変換はブラウザのサポートの問題があります。

特定のブラウザに対するサービスであれば、そのブラウザがサポートの範囲でベストな物が使えるので、より圧縮率の高いフォーマットをサポートしているならそれを使うことで他者より性能上優位に立てることになります。

(WebPを使うのは性能上それがベストだというだけで、こんなマイナーサービスでWebPを使うことで「利用が増えた」とか「普及している」なんて言うつもりはGoogleにはさらさらないでしょう。それがしたいならGoogleにはいくらでも出来ることがあります。)

ブラウザを限定しない汎用的なサービスでは、多くのブラウザでサポートしているであろう汎用的な(≒古い≒性能はあまりよくない)フォーマットを使わざるをえません。