# iOSで4Gの低速通信モードを検出することはできるでしょうか？

Tags: ios

キャリアによって低速通信モードになったとき、
CTTelephonyNetworkInfoのcurrentRadioAccessTechnologyとserviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnologyのどちらでも
"CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE"のままを返すんですが、自前で通信スピードを検知する以外に、OSから低速通信モードになったことを検知することはできるでしょうか？

Comment: 関連質問： [network - 通信先のスマートフォンが通信制限がかかっているか判断するには？　通信制限時には荒い画像を送信して体感速度を上げたい - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/22869) こちらの質問では、HLSという動画配信方式で通信帯域に応じて画質を動的に変更する例が回答されています。質問の趣旨はクライアントアプリケーションでの速度検出のようですが、参考までに